# grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC

Tags: python, p4-lang

When I use the make command to compile P4 code and issue flow rules to the switch. The following error occurred while configuring the switch:

```
Configuring switch s11 using P4Runtime with file ./sw_rules/s11-runtime.json
 - Using P4Info file build/ddosmit.p4.p4info.txt...
 - Connecting to P4Runtime server on 127.0.0.1:50051 (bmv2)...
 - Setting pipeline config (build/ddosmit.json)...
 - Inserting 25 table entries...
 - MyIngress.ipv4_lpm: (default action) => MyIngress.drop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./utils/run_exercise.py", line 396, in <module>
    exercise.run_exercise()
  File "./utils/run_exercise.py", line 207, in run_exercise
    self.program_switches()
  File "./utils/run_exercise.py", line 309, in program_switches
    self.program_switch_p4runtime(sw_name, sw_dict)
  File "./utils/run_exercise.py", line 284, in program_switch_p4runtime
    proto_dump_fpath=outfile)
  File "/home/zwx/p4/ddosmitigation/utils/p4runtime_lib/simple_controller.py", line 129, in program_switch
    insertTableEntry(sw, entry, p4info_helper)
  File "/home/zwx/p4/ddosmitigation/utils/p4runtime_lib/simple_controller.py", line 150, in insertTableEntry
    sw.WriteTableEntry(table_entry)
  File "/home/zwx/p4/ddosmitigation/utils/p4runtime_lib/switch.py", line 101, in WriteTableEntry
    self.client_stub.Write(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 221, in __call__
    compression=compression)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 257, in _with_call
    return call.result(), call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 343, in result
    raise self
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = ""
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1681200476.604114880","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:50051","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1070,"grpc_message":"","grpc_status":2}"
>
utils/Makefile~:27: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

The result I hope to achieve is that the topology is successfully built and the specified flow rules are distributed to the corresponding switches.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've come across such an error was when I tried to insert two conflicting rules. E.g. consider the following table:

```
table t {
  
    key = {
      headers.some_protocol.unsigned_int_field : exact;
    }

    actions = {
      forward;
    }
}
```

As I tried to insert two rules with the same `unsigned_int_field`, same action `forward`, but different action parameters, it threw the error you described.

```py
table_name = 't'
match_field = 1
insert_forward_rule(table_name, match_field, 3)
insert_forward_rule(table_name, match_field, 4) #result = grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError
```

Could this be what is happening in your case?